# ngtagsinput angularjs How to assign id to each tag

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I'm using ngtagsinput (http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/) to add highlight functionality to my app. I can't figure out how dynamically add an id for each tag as its being created.  I will be using this id to edit the styling of each tag item after it has been created.  I saw the demo about custom templates, but this only works if you pre-define the array of tags.  I'm a newb to Angular which is probably the issue... Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the id using an `on-tag-added` handler. I made a very simple logic that appends the number of tags as id, but you can do whatever you want.

```
$scope.onTagAdded = function($tag) {
    var index = $scope.tags.indexOf($tag);
    $scope.tags[index].id = $scope.tags.length;
};
```

And in the HTML:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" on-tag-added="onTagAdded($tag)"></tags-input>
```

You can then use the appended id in your custom template if needed. See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HTSFTiCNDqDLhqlBPFQ1?p=preview).